# Custom multi-scale time formats in d3

Tags: d3.js

`d3.time.scale` has a neat time formatter which uses [multi-scale time formats](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-tickFormat). Is there an API or other way (yet) to specify a [multi-scale time formats](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-tickFormat)?

I know it is possible to create a new `d3.time.format`, but that won't be multi-scale.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The multi-scale time format isn’t exposed as a public API outside of the standard one returned by a [d3.time.scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales)’s [tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-tickFormat) method.

That said, the [implementation itself](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/time/scale.js#L134-143) is fairly simple, so you could create your own multi-scale time format without a lot of work. The multi-scale time format is simply an ordered array of [time formats](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting), each of which has an associated test function. The first test function that returns true determines which time format is used.

The time format used by d3.time.scale has the following formats (taken from [time/scale.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/time/scale.js#L134-143)), specified in reverse order:

```
  [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
  [":%S", function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
  ["%I:%M", function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
  ["%I %p", function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
  ["%a %d", function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
  ["%B", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
  ["%Y", d3_true]
```

So, for example, if the time has a non-zero milliseconds field, then the ".%L" format is used; otherwise, if it has a non-zero seconds field, then ":%S" is used; and so on.

Answer (score 3):

In d3 version 4, `d3.time.format` has changed. Here is a new version of creating a conditional time formatter:

https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#d3-time-format

```
var formatMillisecond = d3.timeFormat(".%L"),
    formatSecond = d3.timeFormat(":%S"),
    formatMinute = d3.timeFormat("%I:%M"),
    formatHour = d3.timeFormat("%I %p"),
    formatDay = d3.timeFormat("%a %d"),
    formatWeek = d3.timeFormat("%b %d"),
    formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%B"),
    formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

function multiFormat(date) {
  return (d3.timeSecond(date) < date ? formatMillisecond
      : d3.timeMinute(date) < date ? formatSecond
      : d3.timeHour(date) < date ? formatMinute
      : d3.timeDay(date) < date ? formatHour
      : d3.timeMonth(date) < date ? (d3.timeWeek(date) < date ? formatDay : formatWeek)
      : d3.timeYear(date) < date ? formatMonth
      : formatYear)(date);
}
```